# Excel CountIf Condition Query

Tags: excel, count, formula, countif

Can you help me draft the formula for the link?  The letters cannot be changed in the sheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdtX7.jpg

Comment: what is the formula you tried at this point?

Comment: i was exploring the =(COUNTIF(BM3:BM14,"A"))-(COUNTIF(BL3:BL14,"A")) but only worked for the arrivals.. midway the figures were already incorrect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this formula for the **arrival**:

```
=IF(C2="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D2)));0)+IF(C3="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D3)));0)+IF(C4="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D4)));0)+IF(C5="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D5)));0)+IF(C6="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D6)));0)+IF(C7="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D7)));0)+IF(C8="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D8)));0)+IF(C9="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D9)));0)+IF(C10="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D10)));0)+IF(C11="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D11)));0)+IF(C12="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D12)));0)+IF(C13="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D13)));0)+IF(C14="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D14)));0)+IF(C15="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D15)));0)+IF(C16="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;D16)));0)
```

Try this formula for the **departure**:

```
=IF(D2="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C2)));0)+IF(D3="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C3)));0)+IF(D4="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C4)));0)+IF(D5="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C5)));0)+IF(D6="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C6)));0)+IF(D7="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C7)));0)+IF(D8="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C8)));0)+IF(D9="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C9)));0)+IF(D10="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C10)));0)+IF(D11="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C11)));0)+IF(D12="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C12)));0)+IF(D13="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C13)));0)+IF(D14="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C14)));0)+IF(D15="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C15)));0)+IF(D16="";SUMPRODUCT(-- ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$24:$A$27;C16)));0)
```

I bet you can shorten it down, but this is a basic idea which you can work on.

In the cells `A24:A27` I defined "A" to "D" so I have a repository of the used letters and I can reuse them. You my have them in other cells

Watch out: These formulas are for arrival cell D19 and departure cell D20. For the following colums, just pull the formula over and excel will adjust the dependencies itself

Comment: I cant seem to make it work.  Thought it would be better for me to include the cell locations..  https://imgur.com/7bc5b3y

Comment: @Zhang I added the whole formular to the answer. Attention: with this formula you need in A24 = A in A25 = B ind A26 = C in A27 = D

These Formulas are for arrival cell D19 and departure cell D20. For the following colums, just pull the formula over and excel will adjust the dependencies itself

Comment: i keep getting an error with the first leg of the fomula.. =IF(C2="";SUMPRODUCT...  the " " is not accepted.. tried also breaking the formulate bit by bit and is still not working

Comment: Just in case, the ive uploaded the file via wetransfer 
  https:// we.tl/nwHoC6bnEn

Comment: It works when I paste the arrival formula into cell D19, have you put A-D into cells A24:A27? And dont use " " for the formula, use ""

Comment: have you put A-D into cells A24:A27 - yes i did

Comment: basically i copy pasted the formula u gave, also added A-D in A24-A27, and is not going through

Comment: we.tl/k7ueemd84P I uploaded the excel sheet here with the arrival formula. My Excel is not in English so please check if the Formula is translated automatically to Egnlish. otherwise I'll give you the translation

Comment: Maybe you have to use other charcaters then ".

Comment: okay now departure doesnt work T_T for some reason the arrival formula works on the file you sent back.. very strange.. i copied and pasted it to my saved file and it doesnt go through.. T_T

Comment: can you also help me save it with the departure.. ill probably use YOUR file as my template tab now

Comment: whoa, i reviewed the formulas and they are exactly the same, but it doesnt work for me.. now i need to build the other formulas using your tab

Comment: here is the file: we.tl/1UADe90Kp8

Comment: MEGA THANKS Kopie!!  Really appreciate your patience and help..!!

Comment: now from 4 sample categories.. need to incporate the ACTUAL ones.. which are 16 in total.. gulp!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked...I think you could still work on the formula, because this one is really long and hardcoded. But as a first draft it should work. Mark the answer as solution if it helped :) thx

Comment: Can i interest you in a more complex arrangement of the same?

Comment: you still got to help me out on the first challenge =)

Answer (score -2):

Try this Formula

```
Arrival =COUNTIF(B2:B7,"=A")
Departure =COUNTIF(B2:B7,"=D")
```

Comment: i cant just use the COUNTIF function because i'm counting the first letters as an arrival, and counting the blank space after the last letter as a departure..

Comment: So add a combination of find() and left() to control what you test for...